# Issues with Batch Queuing?

Tags: batch, schedulebatch, queue, apex-flex-queue, queueable-apex

Has anyone else run into issues where their concurrent batches don't really run concurrently?  Supposedly there is a limit of 5 and beyond that goes to the Flex Queue, but I consistently only have a max of 3 and yet 1 is almost always in the Flex Queue.  I built my business logic around the assumption of five, so this is going to cause me major headaches...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assumptions are not correct.

According to the documentation, all jobs are placed in the queue and processed in the order they are placed in the queue *as resources become available*. The processing of up to 5 jobs at once simply means if enough resources are available up to 5 can be processed at the same time. It does not mean that you can have 5 before they go into the queue:

> Previously, you could submit only up to five batch jobs simultaneously. The Apex flex queue enables you to submit up to 100 batch jobs for execution
>
> **Any jobs that are submitted for execution are in holding status and are placed in the Apex flex queue**
>
> Submitting Jobs by Calling Database.executeBatch
>
> When you submit batch jobs by calling Database.executeBatch, the
> system places your batch job in Holding status before processing the
> job.
>
> The outcome of Database.executeBatch is as follows.
>
> - The batch job is placed in the Apex flex queue, and its status is set to Holding as long as the number of jobs in the flex queue hasn’t
>   reached the maximum of 100.
> - If the Apex flex queue has the maximum number of jobs, Database.executeBatch throws a LimitException and doesn’t add the job
>   to the queue.
>
> When system resources become available, the system picks up the next
> job from the top of the flex queue for processing and changes its
> status to Queued.

https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/FlexQueue

Comment: Very informative, thank you.  Somehow I'd missed that.  As long as it's not waiting on my other batches to finish every time, I'm happy with that.  "As resources become available" I can live with.